# Unable to print all array elements

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to print array inside a for loop but my code is not working. Am I doing something wrong?

```js
var fruits, text, fLen, i;

fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];
fLen = fruits.length;

for (i = 0; i < fLen; i++) {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = fruits[i];
}
```

```html
<h2>JavaScript Arrays</h2>
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: You are overwriting the previous output in each iteration of the loop, so at the end you only see the last fruit's name.

Answer (score 3):

You are overwriting the previous output in each iteration of the loop, so at the end you only see the last fruit's name.

Instead of looping, just use `join`:

```js
var fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];
document.getElementById("demo").textContent = fruits.join('\n');
```

```css
#demo { white-space: pre }
```

```html
<h2>JavaScript Arrays</h2>
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Note that I used CSS (`white-space: pre`) to make sure the newlines are rendered as such.

Answer (score 1):

In each iteration you are overriding the `innnerHTML` with the latest `friuts` item. Use `+=` operator instead of `=` to keep all the previous fruits.

```js
var fruits, text, fLen, i;

fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];
fLen = fruits.length;
for (i = 0; i < fLen; i++) {
   document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += " "+ fruits[i];
 }
```

```html
<h2>JavaScript Arrays</h2>
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

This will help; Use createElement, insert every el of array inside a para tag and insert the para tag as a child of div (with id demo)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h2>JavaScript Arrays</h2>
<div id="demo"></div>

<script>
var fruits, text, fLen, i;

fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];
fLen = fruits.length;
for (i = 0; i < fruits.length; i++) {
  let ptag = document.createElement("p");
  let text = document.createTextNode(fruits[i]);
  ptag.appendChild(text);
   document.getElementById("demo").appendChild(ptag);
 }

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplest approach ids to iterate over the array (i am using a forEach loop)  and build a string from each element and tehn pas that into the html. Note U have changes the display into a ul - since it best represents the content you are displaying.

```js
var str = '';
var fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];

fruits.forEach(function(fruit) {
 str += '<li>' + fruit + '</li>';  
})

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = str;
```

```html
<ul id="demo"></ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

The code you have written overwrites the data that is displayed in the

tag over every iteration. I'd suggest you use the "join()" function

Answer (score 0):

```js
var fruits, text, fLen, i;

fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];
fLen = fruits.length;
for (i = 0; i < fLen; i++) {

   document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += "</br>"+fruits[i]
 }
```

```html
<h2>JavaScript Arrays</h2>
<p id="demo"></p>
```